# where can I find datasets with ground truth communities for disjoint community detection?

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, complex-networks

I have an algorithm in community detection in a complex network but I need a small, medium and large size datasets with ground truth communities. I have found two, named Zarchy karate club and U.S. football team but I need more for evaluation.

Comment: where can I find the bottlenose dolphin ground truth communities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html#communities) dataset. However, note that using ground truth community structures has been criticized in the literature, see ([Lee & Cunningham 2017](http://doi.org/10.1093/comnet/cnt012)), ([Dao *et al*. 2017](http://doi.org/10.1145/3110025.3110053)), ([Chakraborty *et  al*. 2018](http://doi.org/10.1145/3184558.3186921))

Comment: You are right. But I found just large networks on SNAP data set with ground truth communities.

Comment: I don't know how to handle these large datasets.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that? You can also try to generate artificial graphs with planted partition, e.g. using the LFR model (10.1103/PhysRevE.80.016118)